# Why are values being removed from a Hashtable when a parameter with a long value is put into the Hashtable in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code in Kotlin, assume the Bundle has other values like :

```
{
`name`:`John`
`lastname`:`Doe`
`age`:`44`
}
```

So, if the `longString` gets long enough, all these other values get removed along with their keys. What might be causing this? I've tested this outside android with a normal Hashmap and this is not happening.

```
private fun bundleToMap(b: Bundle, longString: String): Hashtable<String, String?>? {
    val map = Hashtable<String, String?>()
    map.put("longString", longString);

    for (key in b.keySet()) {
            map[key] = b.getString(key);
    }
    return map
}
```

Comment: This is not Java.  Please don't tag it with `[java]`

Comment: I also note that your question says it is about `HashMap`, but you are actually using `Hashtable` in your code.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @StephenC I corrected Hashtable, about Java, this is also happening on Java android, I just posted Kotlin here.

Comment: If it is happening in Java, **and you want to know why it is happening in Java**, then you need to include the Java code.  (Or ask a different question about the Java case.)  If you don't want to know why it is happening in Java, then the `[java]` tag is irrelevant.  Tags should relate to the *topic* of the question ... otherwise they are just noise.

Comment: For what it is worth, this behavior you are describing sounds *implausible* to me (certainly in the Java case) so you probably should provide your code in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's weird, this is why I'm looking for help.

Comment: Well ... if you want help, you need to provide something that will allow others ("helpers") to figure out what is going on.  The ball is in your court.  My opinion is that the problem is not happening in that code.  It is happening somewhere else; e.g. in something that is doing something with that map later on.